# Why this type of scrolling occurs in PageViewController?

Tags: ios, swift3, uipageviewcontroller

[image: These are my views in storyboard]
Here in this I am implementing a pageviewcontroller in order to scroll through pages "View 1" ,"View 2" that works fine....but when i click the button in view and move to "Sub view" here also the scrolling occurs from "SubView" -> "View 2"...how to correct this..

Comment: sorry, your question is unclear

Comment: here in the above image there are 2 views "View1" and "View2"...these two are seperatedly connected to two navigational controllers....in the page controller I am using the "restoration identifier" of the navigational controllers to scroll and its working fine......but when i click the button in "view1" and perform segue to "Subview" the problem occurs here the if scroll the "subview" to left side then the "View2" appears...this should not occur...

Comment: can U share sample project ? github or any

Comment: I don't have any...are u clear with my question....

Comment: yeah! Got it. Please upload googleDrive or any & share with us

Comment: here is the link.. https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B2OLBJ1viEUxSzlmS3NuMFBJUzA

Comment: Can't download.

Comment: sry dude...do u have any idea y this occurs...it is just 10mins of coding can u try it and tell...

Comment: Why you added `MenuNavThreeController` into `navarray`?

Comment: I think MenuNavThreeController is represented in Yellow color? Are you?

Comment: hey sry man in image i have just cropped only two views...there is another one below 3rd view...as same as 2nd one...its not   a problem

Answer (score 0):

[The image is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PyGR7.png)

When I designed in this way the problem solved...